# Calculate column averages over specific row ranges from a separate input file

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to calculate averages over a given range specified in one file and applying it to numbers in a different file. I am having trouble finding examples in bash where you can use information from 2 separate files at once. Here's what I am trying to do:

The first file has specified ranges that I want averages for:

**ranges.txt**

```
Sc0  1  5
Sc1  69 72
```

The second file contains the numbers I need to take the averages from (using the 3rd column):

**allNumbers.txt**

```
Sc0 1   30
Sc0 2   40
Sc0 3   40
Sc0 4   50
Sc0 5   10
Sc0 6   30
Sc1 69  40
Sc1 70  10
Sc1 71  20
Sc1 72  30
```

Here's what I'd like to have:
**averages.txt**

```
34
25
```

I am trying to do this in the bash loop shown below, but I am fairly new to bash scripting and this code is not working.

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0;
total=0;
  
while read rangeName rangeStart rangeStop            #make column variables for range.txt 
    while read name position sum                     #make column variables for allNumbers.txt                        
        while [$rangeName == $name && $rangeStart < $position <= $rangeStop]; do
            for i in $sum; do
                total=$(echo $total+$i | bc)
                ((count++))
            done
            echo "$total / $count" | bc          #print out averages
        done     
    done < allNumbers.txt
done < ranges.txt
```

Can someone help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site. As a general rule, please always explain _how_ an attempt you describe in your question didn't work as expected, since this can give contributors valuable input on how to help you solve the problem.

Comment: Okay, I will do that next time.Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really don't want to use the shell for this. First because it doesn't do floating point math so you need to call `bc` or another tool, second because the syntax is very complicated, as you can see, and third because it is *slow*. See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716) for more details.

Pretty much any other language would be better, but here's one approach using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]["start"]=$2; a[$1]["end"]=$3; next}
       { 
        if($2>=a[$1]["start"] && $2<=a[$1]["end"]){
            values[$1]+=$3; 
            nums[$1]++;
        }
       }
       END{
        for(range in values){
            print values[range]/nums[range]
        }
       }' ranges allNumbers
34
25
```

And here's the same thing as an annotated script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

## If we are reading the first file
NR==FNR{
  ## $1 is the range name, so this will save the
  ## start position for this range name as a[$1]["start"] and
  ## the end position as a[$1]["end"]
  a[$1]["start"]=$2;
  a[$1]["end"]=$3;
  ## skip to the next line 
  next
}
## This will only run for the second file
{
  ## If this value falls in the relevant range
  if($2>=a[$1]["start"] && $2<=a[$1]["end"]){
    ## Sum the values of this range and save
    ## in the values array
    values[$1]+=$3;
    ## Count the number of values for this range and save
    ## in the 'nums' array.
    nums[$1]++;
  }
}
## After we've read both files
END{
  ## For each range in the 'values' array
  for(range in values){
    ## print the average
    print values[range]/nums[range]
  }
}
```

You can run either the first one-liner, or save the above as `foo.awk`, make it executable and run:

```
foo.awk ranges allNumbers
```

Comment: It did cross my mind about the wisdom of attempting this in the shell, so I suppose it's time to upskill on another language. Regardless, thanks for your help!